# How to use FIFO with dup2?

Tags: c, linux, fifo, dup2

I have 2 processes, one reads from the input a filename, this filename is then given to the child process.The child process determinates in which directories the given file exits and the child procces gives all the directory names back to the parent who then prints these directory names.I need to do this using FIFO(named pipes).I put the filename directly to systemcall to check if the FIFO would work with it but it doesn't work and I cant't figure out how to do this could someone please help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
//#include <string.h>
extern int errno;

#define FIFO "/tmp/fifo0003.1"
#define FIFO2 "/tmp/fifo0004.1"
int main (void)
{   

int r_fifo, w_fifo, r_fifo2, w_fifo2;
   char filename[100];
   printf("enter filename:");
   scanf("%s",filename);
   char buf[100];
   char buf2[100];
   int fd;
   pid_t pid;
   int stdoutCopy=dup(1);
  if ((mkfifo (FIFO, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) == -1) {
    if(errno == EEXIST)

 perror ("mkfifo()");
 else {
perror("mkfifo()");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
 }   }


if ((mkfifo (FIFO2, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) == -1) {
    if(errno == EEXIST)

 perror ("mkfifo()");
 else {
perror("mkfifo()");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
 }   }

 pid = fork ();
  if (pid == -1)
 {      perror ("fork()");
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else if (pid > 0) {
/*parent writes to fifo */
 if ((w_fifo = open (FIFO, O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
 perror ("open()");
 exit (EXIT_FAILURE);      }
 write (w_fifo, filename, strlen (filename));

/*wait for child */
 while (wait (NULL) != pid);
  /*read FIFO2 */
 if ((r_fifo2 = open (FIFO2, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
 perror ("open()");
 exit (EXIT_FAILURE);      }
//redo stdout
dup2(stdoutCopy,1);
close(stdoutCopy);
read(r_fifo2,buf,strlen(buf));
 buf[strlen(buf)] = '\0';
printf("%s\n",buf);
 else {
     /*child procces */
  if ((r_fifo = open (FIFO, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
 perror ("open()");
 exit (EXIT_FAILURE);      }
 /*read FIFO */
   read (r_fifo, filename, strlen (filename));
 if ((w_fifo2 = open (FIFO2, O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
 perror ("open()");
 exit (EXIT_FAILURE);      }

  dup2(w_fifo2,1);
  system("find -name file1>w_fifo2");
  close(w_fifo2);
   /* EOF */
 exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);}
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;}
```

Comment: Re "*I need to do this using FIFO(named pipes)*", That's not natural. Is this an assignment?

Comment: @ikegami yes, it is

Comment: do  not see `struct pollfd pfd[1]; pfd[0].fd = pipe;  pfd[0].events = POLLIN;  poll(pfd, 1 , 1000);` or so

Comment: Could you please indent your code properly? That's not readable.

Comment: What's the use of `stdoutCopy`? I don't see it serving any purpose. Doing `stdoutCopy = dup(1)` followed by `dup2(stdoutCopy, 1)` is basically the same as `dup2(1, 1)`.

Comment: And you *still* use `strlen` on uninitialized arrays to get the array length. That simply won't work! To get the size of an array use `sizeof`. And you ***must*** use what `read` returns to know the number of bytes that was read into the buffer (and to check for errors as well!)

Comment: I wasn't sure if it would work so I search how to undo dup2 of stdout and this was a solution for it

Comment: But you don't need to "undo" duplication of standard output, especially since you don't do it in the parent process which have an unmodified standard output.

Comment: aa right, I forgot that.Thank you! Do you have any suggestion how I could get this work .I don't know if the dup2 is working or not because the program isn't printing out anyting It looks like it's in a loop .after the systemcall I changed dup2 back to one and put a printf after it but it won't execute it

Answer (score 1):

The shell-command

```
find -name file1>w_fifo2
```

will redirect standard output to a *file* named `w_fifo2`.

If you want the output of the command to be written to your pipe, represented by the `w_fifo2` *descriptor* in your code, then you should duplicate it into `STDOUT_FILENO` just like you do now, but ***not*** redirect output in the command you run:

```
find -name file1
```

---

Also remember that some implementations of `find` require a path as the first argument, or the command would fail:

```
find . -name file1
```

Talking about failure, you really should check what `system` returns to check for failure. And if you want to get output written to standard error (which is the normal channel for error reports and output) you need to replace it with your pipe as well:

```
dup2(w_fifo2, STDERR_FILENO);
```

Comment: could you please provide some code so far I only changed this: system("find -name file1>w_fifo2") to this system("find -name file1)  and I don't know what to do next:((